# data not posting mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

I am trying to post my data from client side to server and its not working, no errors or anything just its not going in the database. Even in another table of users the data is posting but in this products table data is not getting posted.

my data posting code:

```js
    const saveData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/prods");
      const json = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        const addUser = await fetch("/api/prods", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            pname: Name,
            date: new Date().toLocaleString(),
            desc: Desc,
            price: Price,
            ratings: 0,
            image: Image,
            bannner: Banner,
            category: Category,
          }),
        });
        //
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
      };
```

Also i have set a proxy in `package.json`:

```json
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Inputs for data setting:

```html
    <input
            type={"text"}
            placeholder="Name"
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type={"number"}
            placeholder="Price"
            onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type={"text"}
            placeholder="Desc"
            onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type={"text"}
            placeholder="Category"
            onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
          />
          <FileBase64
            multiple={false}
            onDone={({ base64 }) => setImage(base64)}
          />
          <FileBase64
            multiple={false}
            onDone={({ base64 }) => setBanner(base64)}
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => saveData()}>Submit</button>
```

post model:

```js
    const prodScheme = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        pname: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        date: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        desc: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        price: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        ratings: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        image: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        bannner: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        category: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: true,
      }
    );
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("Prod", prodScheme);
```

This is my products controller:

```js
    const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
    const Prod = require("../model/prodsModel");

        const postProds = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      if (!req.body.pname) {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Please enter a name");
      }
    
      const Prod = await Prod.create({
        pname: req.body.pname,
        date: req.body.date,
        desc: req.body.desc,
        price: req.body.price,
        ratings: req.body.ratings,
        image: req.body.image,
        bannner: req.body.bannner,
        category: req.body.category,
      });
    
      res.json(Prod);
    });

    module.exports = {
    getProds,
          postProds,
          updateProds,
          delProds,
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Are you certain `response.ok` is true?

Comment: Have you checked the network pane in dev tools to see if the POST is a 200?

Comment: Through the user interface, trigger `saveData` to load and then look at the https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/ pane. Acutally it looks ok in your screenshot, but its possible they are also the GETs and not the POST.

Comment: it is POST and its a 200

Comment: In this case, its possible (even likely) the problem is in the back end and not the front end. You have verified its all good on front end, you now need to debug the back end to ensure it makes the call to the DB when you expect it to.

Comment: i dont understand everything is also looking good in the backend

Comment: Are you 100% certain? Just before the call is made to MongoDB, add some logging to ensure this is definitely called

Comment: I am sure bcz in another table of USERS the data is being posted and getting aswell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248990/discussion-between-khuzaima-amir-and-adsy).

Comment: Right, but this isn't enough info to be sure. The reason is in the other call, its likely valid data, whereas in this call, probably there is some unknown issue with the data. You need to debug for the specific request that is not working, and not the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have re-initializing the `const` variable `Prod`:

```js
const Prod = require("../model/prodsModel");

// Here, you are re-initializing Prod variable
const Prod = await Prod.create({...});
```

Try changing the name to small case `prod`:

```js
const Prod = require("../model/prodsModel");

const prod = await Prod.create({...});
```